# Different tune for chapter 3 of Eicha?

Tags: tisha-bav, trop-cantillation, lamentations-eicha

Why does the third perek of Eicha have a different melody? Is it just to match the triplet form of the words?

Comment: Note that not all communities use the alternate tune.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't heard of that before I read this.

Comment: [Here](http://virtualcantor.com/Eicha3b.mp3) is one tune people use.

Comment: It generally starts low and gets higher for the three lines, before going low again at the end of the third line.

Comment: I heard this for the first time last night. I thought it was an anomaly since each chapter had a different reader.

Comment: @jake [Here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707941/Rabbi_Jeremy_Wieder/MegillotEichahEichah3) is another.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting, I have never heard that one before.

Comment: And [another](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT6xOXl5GzY).

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think the first two are just different personal styles within the same tune.

Comment: The only place I ever heard the alternative paining was when I lived in Elizabeth ,NJ. I davened in the North ave shul (Rabbi Teitz, shlita) and his son lained the third perek that way.

Comment: I’ve never heard of anything but one tune sung for Eichah, though often in a different key for each chapter.

Comment: And [another](https://youtu.be/Oc5u24qxMRc?t=156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are those that do Chapter 3 with a different tune due to its different rhythm.

http://www.masorti.org.il/uploads/uploads/MegilatEichaSample.pdf

> פרק ג׳ הוא 'קינה אישית' למעט באותיות נ׳ וס׳, המנוסחות בלשון רבים. שאר
>   הקינות מדברות על גורלו המר של העם הסובל מחורבנו ומחורבן ארצו, עירו
>   ומקדשו. נגינת הטעמים של 'איכה' אף היא מלנכולית ומזכירה בכי ונהי. יש
>   הנוהגים לקרוא את פרק ג׳ במנגינה אחרת, בגלל המקצב השונה שלו.‏

Comment: I must say you are not who I was expecting to post our first [pluralistic post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1298/759).